# does azure search replica/Partitions impact index update speed?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have an azure search instance(s1, 2 replica, 2 Partitions) created in 2016, and when I tried to upload 50 million rows to this instance, we found out that the old instance still has a limit of 30million records.

No problem, I created a new azure search instance (s1, 1 replica, 1 Partition), and start to upload the same data up. To my surprise, the uploading speed is much better on the new instance comparing to the old one (almost double the update speed).

I am wondering what could be the reason? The index I was uploading to is a new index, so no one will query it. These are the differences I can see between new and old search index:

1. No query traffic in the new search instance, old search instance
   does get traffic from production environment. But it is on other search indexes.
2. New search instance has 1 replica, 1 Partition, old one has 2 replica, 2 partitions.

Just very curious on why I see such a speed difference. If I run a search query, actually, the performance will be very similar between old and new. Just the index update speed is much much better.

Comment: I played bit more, looks like if any traffic is accessing the index (e.g. query or a manual index update from .net sdk), the indexer will become very slow. Possibly it is trying to minimise the impact on the query performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query traffic is a factor, but it could also be the replica count. Every replica adds work to the indexing process, while every partition adds to the parallelism available for indexing. If you added a partition to your new service and indexing sped up further, that wouldn't be a surprising result.

All that said, the most likely explanation in your case is that your new service is running on [faster hardware](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/azure-search-unlimited-document-counts/) than the old one. This is how we were able to remove the document limit for new services.